# WPF how to reference application resource from merged dictionary?

Tags: wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

So if I have a converter in the resource dictionary for my app like so:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <Converters:ColorToBrushConverter x:Key="ColorToBrushConverter" />


      <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="ResourceDictionaries/GraphViewerBrushes.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="ResourceDictionaries/ColorPickerResources.xaml" />
      </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>



    </ResourceDictionary>
  </Application.Resources>
```

How can I reference the converter from within one of the external xaml files? or is this not possible? i know i could just reinstance another converter there, but that seems wasteful.

Comment: What do you mean by external XAML files?

Comment: oh i just meant the stuff in the merged dictionary. reed answered my question though. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DynamicResource` instead of `StaticResource` to reference the converter.  This will cause it to look up the resource dynamically, which should succeed as it's part of the Application resources.

That being said, I typically just create another instance, as it is simpler, and a converter has very, very little overhead to create (since it should have no state).